# TypeError: implement_array_function expected 6 arguments, got 5

Tags: python, scipy, typeerror

I have en issue I don't know how to handle since it's not due to my code but rather numpy.scipy code.

```
File "D:\dev/Teo/trunk/SWDS/functions\Functions_get_data.py", line 15, in <module>
    from scipy.io import loadmat

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\__init__.py", line 98, in <module>
    from .matlab import loadmat, savemat, whosmat

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from ._mio import loadmat, savemat, whosmat

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\_mio.py", line 9, in <module>
    from ._mio4 import MatFile4Reader, MatFile4Writer

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\io\matlab\_mio4.py", line 8, in <module>
    import scipy.sparse

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py", line 283, in <module>
    from . import csgraph

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.py", line 185, in <module>
    from ._laplacian import laplacian

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_laplacian.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py", line 120, in <module>
    from ._isolve import *

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_isolve\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .lgmres import lgmres

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_isolve\lgmres.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scipy.linalg import get_blas_funcs

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\__init__.py", line 207, in <module>
    from ._decomp_schur import *

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\scipy\linalg\_decomp_schur.py", line 179, in <module>
    eps = numpy.finfo(float).eps

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 504, in __new__
    obj = object.__new__(cls)._init(dtype)

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 511, in _init
    machar = _get_machar(dtype)

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 350, in _get_machar
    return _discovered_machar(ftype)

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\getlimits.py", line 357, in _discovered_machar
    return MachAr(lambda v: array([v], ftype),

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_machar.py", line 121, in __init__
    self._do_init(float_conv, int_conv, float_to_float, float_to_str, title)

  File "C:\Users\Teo.beaudelain\.conda\envs\SWD_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_machar.py", line 137, in _do_init
    if any(temp1 - one != zero):

  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 180, in any

TypeError: implement_array_function expected 6 arguments, got 5
```

I have already uninstalled and reinstalled scypi by running conda uninstall scipy the conda install scipy.
Additional info : I use an specific anaconda env. I use loadmat from scipy only for loading .mat file.

Comment: Sounds like a version mismatch between `numpy` and `scipy`, though I don't  find any evidence on the Web about such an issue.  I don't know about this `SWD_env`, and whether it affects the the `conda` reload or not.